# Highlight lines above cursor

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression, highlight

I was looking for a way to *highlight* lines above the cursor line to mark them as *done*, whatever that means in the context of what I'm doing.

I came up with this `match Comment /\_.*\%#.*/` or, in words, *highlight everything including newlines up until the cursor character, and then the rest of the line too as comment text*

This does the job and allows me to easily progress through a document/source file by moving the cursor down, but the problem is: It's slow. REALLY slow.

Is there some better way to achieve the same result? I don't mind it involving a lot of magic, since I will most likely hide it away behind a function in my vimrc anyway, but I am restricted to only vimscript.

Comment: @Rich Ah, yes, that was a mistake. It's fixed now, thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 2):

For me, simply using syntax matching by prepending `syntax` seems to make it acceptably fast:

```
syntax match Comment /\_.*\%#.*/
```

If that's not fast enough for you, perhaps you can alter your `sync` setting. See `:help :syn-sync`. I presumed this setting was why using syntax matching is faster than `:match` for this expression, but even using `:syntax sync fromstart` it still works fast for me (in the files I've tested it in).

If that's still no good, you could try setting up a syntax region instead:

```
syntax region Error start=/\%^/ end=/\%#.*/
```

This matches the beginning of the file and the cursor position, but nothing in between, so I imagine it would be super fast.